# Pass value form one window form to another Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView on my first windows Form. where a user click then it open a popup where is second DataGridView, click on row of DataGridView that will display on first page DataGridView.

The problem is that when i click on `Form` one DataGridView it open popup of second Form, where user select any row. I take my required data from that DataGridView and send these data on First page that is previously open on my window. From this line of code i pass the value from Second Form to First Form .

```
FrmSetting _frmSetting = new FrmSetting(string _val,string code)
```

I think because of new keyword it open a new page or something like that . How can i send on First Form please suggest me .

Thanks

Comment: @Dilshod yes this is winForm

Answer (score 2):

Create property on Second form and set the selected value to that property. Then you can get it from first form.

UPDATE:

```
//this should be in second form
string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
    get{return _myProperty;}
    set{_myProperty=value; if(MyPropertyChanged!=null)MyPropertyChanged(this,null);}
}

public event EventHandler MyPropertyChanged;

//assign value to MyProperty when your dataGrid changes or whatever
```

Then from your first form you can say:

```
string valueFromSecondForm = secondForm.MyProperty;
//subscribe to MyPropertyChanged event if you need to know when it is changed
```

if you need some info from first form you can do the same thing.

Comment: the same way you would subscribe an event to a button click event, so the same thing with the event `_frmSetting.MyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the first form as a parameter to the constructor for the second form.  Make the DataGrid that you want to update in the first form public and update it from the second form:

```
Form1.DataGrid1.CaptionText = "Caption 1";
```

Comment: Form1.contol.Text = "Hello" Here what is `.Control1` and What is `"Hello"`

Comment: I changed Control1 to DataGrid1